# "ubuntu-desktop" and "ubuntu-gnome-desktop" packages got purged, but everything seems ok

Tags: package-management, gnome-shell-extension

I wanted to purge/reinstall the `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator` package, but when I did that, two other packages `ubuntu-desktop` and `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` got purged with it.

So I restarted, thinking that I probably need to reinstall those, but everything seems ok! I always thought those two are some critical packages.

Should I reinstall them?

I have 18.04 installed.

Comment: `ubuntu-desktop` and `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` are [metapackages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages). That is, they don't contain any software, but are set to *depend* on the packages which make up the desktop. So when you install `ubuntu-desktop` you will automatically get all the necessary packages, because they are dependencies. When you removed appindicator, `ubuntu-desktop` got removed too because it no longer had all the necessary dependencies.

Comment: If you are reinstalling that appindicator package, I don't see the downside to reinstalling the metapackages, and putting your system back in its prior state.